Is async method use thread pool thread when await occur to complete awaiting task?
I have run this code, after  await Task.Delay(5000) I can see, which thread started the method execution which is differ, after await block execution, also that was thread pool as well.
static async Task Method3()
{
    MetaInfoHelper("Method 3");

    Console.WriteLine("Method 3 is about to execute ....");
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    MetaInfoHelper("Method 3");
    Console.WriteLine("Method 3 completed execution.");

    MetaInfoHelper("Method 3");
}

static void MetaInfoHelper(string methodName)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{methodName} IsThreadPoolThread : {Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread}, ManagedThreadId : {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} , IsBackground : {Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground}");
}

Output:
Method 3 IsThreadPoolThread : False, ManagedThreadId : 1 , IsBackground : False

Method 3 is about to execute ....

Method 3 IsThreadPoolThread : True, ManagedThreadId : 8 , IsBackground : True

Method 3 completed execution.

Method 3 IsThreadPoolThread : True, ManagedThreadId : 8 , IsBackground : True


Related: What thread runs the code after the await keyword?

It will depend on the execution "context". From the sample I'm guessing you are running a console application. This has a main thread, but any "continuations", i.e. anything after an await, will run on the threadpool [*].
In an UI application there is a UI context. So anything that is awaited on the UI thread will continue running on that thread. But anything awaited on any non UI thread will continue on an arbitrary thread pool thread.
See How Async/Await Really Works in C# for details.
[*] This may depend on the method, state of the task, and other details. I would recommend reading the more detailed resources if you need some specific behavior.

"anything after an await, will run on the threadpool." -- Not nesessarily. It depends on the implementation of the asynchronous method. The Task.Delay completes indeed on the ThreadPool by design.
